# Notepad++ Joining a line containing a pattern to the previous line

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list of data containing table names and table parameters.
In some of the cases, there is supplemental data containing the keyword **SourceTableName**

```
Table:dbo_mlo_city;ODBC;DSN=blah;
SourceTableName:blah

Table:dbo_mlo_city;ODBC;DSN=blah
blah
```

I want to append any line starting with SourceTableName to the one before it.
so that, in the above example, I am left with:

```
Table:dbo_mlo_city;ODBC;DSN=blah;SourceTableName:blah
Table:dbo_mlo_city;ODBC;DSN=blah
blah
```

I had hoped this worked with NotePad++:

```
replace \nSourceTableName
with SourceTableName
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `\r\n(SourceTableName.*)` 
with `\1`

Or, to also get rid of a possible blank line after it,
replace `\r\n(SourceTableName.*)(?:\r\n)?` with `\1`

Be sure to uncheck `. matches newline`

Ref: [finding newline in notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133965/find-crlf-in-notepad)

Comment: doh!... I forgot about the parentheses... and the \r. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

The find and replace will achieve this.  Use: `\r\n` in the Regular expression search mode as follows:

[image: Replace]